# Java. Display one element from 2D array

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm new to Java and programming at all. Is it possible to display just one element from 2D String[][] array if I know row and column number?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println(array[n][m])
```

Where `n` and `m` are indexes.